# Jquery - How to apply it for each item separately?

Tags: jquery

How to apply it for each item separately?

It is required that not all elements are revealed when hovering, but only the one on which they were led

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
    $("ul.product-categories > li > ul").toggle();

    $("ul.product-categories > li").hover(function () {
        $("ul.product-categories > li > ul").toggle();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {        
    $("ul.product-categories > li > ul").toggle();

    $("ul.product-categories > li").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('> ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: It should be `$(this).find('> ul')` if it has to be identical to `$("ul.product-categories > li > ul")`

Comment: @t.niese nice catch

Comment: Corrected: Event listener needed a semicolon.

Comment: @mehulmpt, thank you!!

Comment: @RacilHilan The semicolon there was optional. Most of the semicolons in js at the end of a statment are not required. But it is true that the code should be consistent, either leave out the semicolon for each statment or use it for each statment.

Comment: @t.niese You explained the obvious, that's JavaScript basics. However, it's not really a matter of consistency, the recommendation is to always use semicolons, and nearly all JavaScript tools enforce that.

Comment: @RacilHilan That's a matter of opinion. There is a large number of projects that uses [standardjs](https://standardjs.com/) as style guide. And this guide line says to not use semicolons. I just wanted to say that there is no **need** for that semicolon, neither for logical correctness nor for syntactical correctness, just for consistency and as comment (instead of a `Edit Summary`) it sounds like the semicolon is relevant.

Comment: @t.niese OK, fine. It is a matter of opinion if you like, but if you read all the arguments made by standardjs you must admit that it is for professional JavaScripters. Most, if not all, beginners don't read the rules and it is much easier for them to use semicolons consistently. Once they become experienced and learn all the rules, it can be then a matter of style, but like you said must be consistent. One last note: standardjs does not stop you from using semicolons, it only does not enforce them.

Comment: Relax guys. It's all good as long as you know what you're doing and you're in control! Happy new year :)

Comment: We are relaxed. It's a friendly debate :). The problem with JavaScript is that most developers are not experienced in JavaScript. They only use small snippets in their projects coded in various other languages. It is therefore much easier for them to always use semicolons similar to the other languages they use in their projects rather than learn all the JavaScript rules. For bigger JavaScript code done by experienced JavaScript developers, I agree with t.niese that it is a matter of style (or opinion). They must know what they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'this', it relates to the actual item being interacted with.

```
$("ul.product-categories > li").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggle();
})
```